# Setting up ConceptNet5 locally

Tags: python, sqlite, nlp, corpus, reasoning

I am trying to set up [ConceptNet5 (link)](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/) locally onto my system. ConceptNet has 3 APIs Lookup, Search and Association api which is given onto [this page(link)](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/API). I tried to set up these Apis locally as described into [Running your own copy](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Running-your-own-copy). The command in the end "make all" did half of the process successfully, which made lookup and search apis working locally, but association api is not working locally as "make all" gave error in between. So basically, my sqlite database has data for lookup and search, but data for association api is missing. I am getting this error while doing "make all"

```
if [ ! -e ~/.conceptnet5 ]; then ln -s /media/D8849AB0849A911C/conceptnet_data_home/data ~/.conceptnet5; fi
python3 -m conceptnet5.builders.merge_vector_spaces /media/D8849AB0849A911C/conceptnet_data_home/data/assoc/subspaces
Merging: part_00 + part_01 -> merged_a0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/Downloads/conceptNet_new_python2.7/conceptnet5/conceptnet5/builders/merge_vector_spaces.py", line 58, in <module>
    merge_8_vector_spaces(args.input_dir)
  File "/root/Downloads/conceptNet_new_python2.7/conceptnet5/conceptnet5/builders/merge_vector_spaces.py", line 18, in merge_8_vector_spaces
    merge_vector_spaces(subspace_dir, mergers)
  File "/root/Downloads/conceptNet_new_python2.7/conceptnet5/conceptnet5/builders/merge_vector_spaces.py", line 46, in merge_vector_spaces
    merged = spaceA.merged_with(spaceB, k=k)
AttributeError: 'AssocSpace' object has no attribute 'merged_with'
make: *** [/media/D8849AB0849A911C/conceptnet_data_home/data/assoc/assoc-space-5.3/u.npy] Error 1
```

Its giving error into the code which I am unable to figure out. How can I make it work. I checked the code which is also there onto [Github(link)](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/blob/master/conceptnet5/builders/merge_vector_spaces.py). But couldn't find any solution yet. Help is appreciated.